# Google translation API, misbehaviour on Android Chrome

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, google-api

I am using google translator API to get regional language input in my website (which is responsive). It suppose to translate each word after pressing space, this works fine on desktop browsers even in chrome. It also works fine on Android Default Browser and other Android browsers. But when using same on Android Chrome Browser translator didn't respond on space but surprisingly if I press go or new line on keyboard it translates word. I don't understand why this is happening. And how to control it.

Here is my Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

google.load("elements", "1", {
    packages: "transliteration"
});

function onLoad() {
    var options = {
        sourceLanguage: google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.ENGLISH,
        destinationLanguage: [google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.HINDI],
        shortcutKey: 'ctrl+g',
        transliterationEnabled: true
    };
    if (google.elements.transliteration.isBrowserCompatible()) {
        var control = new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);
        control.makeTransliteratable(['transliterateTextarea']);
        document.getElementById('errorDiv').innerHTML = 'Supported';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('errorDiv').innerHTML = 'Sorry! Your browser does not support transliteration';
    }
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad);
```

Control Code:

```
<div class="Google-transliterate-Way2blogging">
    Type in Hindi (Press Ctrl+g to toggle between English and Hindi)<br>
    <textarea id="transliterateTextarea" style="width:600px;height:200px"></textarea>
    <span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:10px;float:right;margin:5px;"></span>
    <span id="errorDiv"></span>
</div>
```

The site is in ASP.Net MVC
I dint find any documentation on this.

Comment: do you find any solution to this

Comment: Pressing enter after word translates on mobile.

Comment: How have you solved problem with enter key? Can i visit the website?